# Update price list when button pressed - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of items and prices and would like to be able to press a button to update the price in the list based on another cell.

Here is an example:

[Example of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUiOz.png)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

I've looked online but been unable to work out how to do this thus far.

I've started to assemble a script, but it's not quite right

```
function Update() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSht = ss.getSheetByName("Pack Values");
  var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName("Prices");
  
  var sValue = formSht.getRange("H1").getValue();
var sData = recordsSht.getDataRange().getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < sData.length; i++){
  var row = sData[i];
  if(row[0] == sValue){
    var uValues = 
    [[formSht.getRange("H1").getValue(),
    formSht.getRange("I1").getValue()]];
    recordsSht.getRange(i+1,1,1,2).setValues(uValues);
  }  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using the following:

```js
function Update() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSht = ss.getSheetByName("Pack Values");
  var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName("Prices");
  
  var sValue = formSht.getRange("H1").getValue();
  var sData = recordsSht.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < sData.length; i++) {
    var row = sData[i];
    if (row[0] == sValue) {
      var uValues = [[formSht.getRange("H1").getValue(), formSht.getRange("I1").getValue()]];
      recordsSht.getRange(i+1,1,1,2).setValues(uValues);
    }  
  }
}
```